# How do i make interactive NPCs?

Tags: pygame

Hello i am making a graphic adventure/rpg with pygame.
Is there a way to make NPCs with pygame, and be able to interact with them, like having a dialog ?
I've been searching on the internet but i didn't have useful results. It would be great if someone could help me.

Here is the main code.

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from os import path
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from tiledmap import *
from pgu import gui
from pygame.draw import circle
import pygame_ai as pai
import time


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        game_folder = path.dirname(__file__)
        img_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'img')
        map_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'maps')
        self.map = TiledMap(path.join(map_folder, 'mapa_inici.tmx'))
        self.map_img = self.map.make_map()
        self.map_rect = self.map_img.get_rect()
        self.player_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, PLAYER_IMG)).convert_alpha()

    def new(self):
        # iniciar totes les variables i fer tota la preparació per a una nova partida
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        #for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map.data):
           #for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
                #if tile == '1':
                    #Wall(self, col, row)
                #if tile == 's':
                    #self.player = Player(self, col, row)
        for tile_object in self.map.tmxdata.objects:
            if tile_object.name == 'Jugador':
                self.player = Player(self, tile_object.x, tile_object.y)
            if tile_object.name == 'Muro':
                Obstacle(self, tile_object.x, tile_object.y, tile_object.width, tile_object.height)
        self.camera = Camera(self.map.width, self.map.height)

    def run(self):
        # bucle del joc - s'iguala self.playing = False per finalitzar el joc
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        # update portion of the game loop
        self.all_sprites.update()
        self.camera.update(self.player)

    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.map_img, self.camera.apply_rect(self.map_rect))
        for sprite in self.all_sprites:
            self.screen.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite))
        pg.display.flip()

    def events(self):
        # tots els events
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()

g = Game()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
```

The sprites code

```
import pygame as pg
from os import path
import sys
from settings import *
import pygame_ai as pai
from tiledmap import TiledMap
vec = pg.math.Vector2



class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.player_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.pos = vec(x, y)
        self.rot = 0

    def get_keys(self):
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.vel.x = -PLAYER_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.vel.x = PLAYER_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
            self.vel.y = -PLAYER_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
            self.vel.y = PLAYER_SPEED
        if self.vel.x != 0 and self.vel.y != 0:
            self.vel *= 0.7071

    def collide_walls(self,dir):
        if dir == 'x':
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
            if hits:
                if self.vel.x > 0:
                    self.pos.x = hits[0].rect.left - self.rect.width
                if self.vel.x < 0:
                    self.pos.x = hits[0].rect.right
                self.vel.x = 0
                self.rect.x = self.pos.x
        if dir == 'y':
            hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
            if hits:
                if self.vel.y > 0:
                    self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top - self.rect.height
                if self.vel.y < 0:
                    self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.bottom
                self.vel.y = 0
                self.rect.y = self.pos.y

    def update(self):
        self.get_keys()
        self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt
        self.rect.x = self.pos.x
        self.collide_walls('x')
        self.rect.y = self.pos.y
        self.collide_walls('y')

class Obstacle(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, w, h):
        self.groups = game.walls
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.rect = pg.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

The tile map code

import pygame as pg
import pytmx
from settings import *

class Map:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data = []
        with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                self.data.append(line.strip())

        self.tilewidth = len(self.data[0])
        self.tileheight = len(self.data)
        self.width = self.tilewidth * TILESIZE
        self.height = self.tileheight * TILESIZE

class TiledMap:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
        self.width = tm.width * tm.tilewidth
        self.height = tm.height * tm.tileheight
        self.tmxdata = tm

    def render(self, surface):
        ti = self.tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
        for layer in self.tmxdata.visible_layers:
            if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x, y, gid, in layer:
                    tile = ti(gid)
                    if tile:
                        surface.blit(tile, (x * self.tmxdata.tilewidth, y * self.tmxdata.tileheight))

    def make_map(self):
        temp_surface = pg.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.render(temp_surface)
        return temp_surface

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.camera = pg.Rect(0,0,width,height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def apply_rect(self, rect):
        return rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        x = -target.rect.centerx + int(WIDTH / 2)
        y = -target.rect.centery + int(HEIGHT / 2)

        # limit al seguiment del personatge
        x = min(0,x) # esquerra
        y = min(0,y) # part de dalt
        x = max(-(self.width - WIDTH), x) # dreta
        y = max(-(self.height - HEIGHT), y) # part de baix
        self.camera = pg.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
```

Comment: There's no built-in way to do it. You'll have to create that functionality yourself, which is far too broad of a question for anybody here to help you with.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. Could you please specify what you mean by dialog, or interactions with NPCs?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, but this question covers a very broad range of concepts and problems to explain in an answer. You should break down your idea of an NPC dialog system into smaller individual problems and try implementing each piece. It would be best to ask a question once you run into a problem implementing one of those pieces. For example, the first small problem may be to try getting a variable to be set when you "talk" or interact with an NPC in the level. Next, draw a text box when that variable is changed. And so on...

Answer (score 1):

In the 1960's there was a simple dialogue-like handler named [Eliza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA).  Since then there has been many changes and variations, and they have become known as "chat bots".  Perhaps your NPCs could have an Eliza-like conversation with the player?  It might be worth doing some research on these sort of natural text processors.

However if you mean simply choosing conversation topics from, say an [(a), (b), (c)] type list, these dialogues would typically be mapped out in a graph of choices.  Have you read stories where you make [choices to change the narrative](http://chooseyourstory.com/)?  These are a simple graph of choices.  You could draw them out on a piece of paper then encode them into a data-structure, maybe a python dictionary.  Each option moves to another node in the graph.  Perhaps they also loop around back upon themselves.